# Android Studio 3: latest plugin version installed but outdated runtime warning

Tags: android, kotlin

On my Android Studio 3.1.3 a new project with this `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

It gives this warning message:

```
Outdated Kotlin Runtime
        Your version of Kotlin runtime in 'Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.30@jar' library is 1.2.30-release-78 (1.2.30), while plugin version is 1.2.50-release-Studio3.1-1.
        Runtime library should be updated to avoid compatibility problems.
        Update Runtime Ignore
```

What are the steps for upgrading the kotlin runtime library that is outdated?

My `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.pilab.toxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file for your module also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `build.gradle` needs changing. Do it like this:

You are using `stdlib-jre7`this instead of `stdlib-jdk7` because `stdlib-jre7` is **deprecated** now, that's why you are getting this warning.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

 }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
```

Comment: Many Thanks! Just a comment about `stdlib-jre7`: it was configured automatically by the new project wizard of android studio, not by me ...very strange, perhaps I did something wrong when creating the project.

Comment: @attdona no you didn't do anything wrong. Android studio by default  configures stdlib-jre7 and then gives the warning :P.